# Login system - Session cookie not set for the first time

Tags: php, mysql

I created a login/register system from scratch by following various tutorials and reading articles online. The system works but there is a bug which I don't understand. When a user tries to login for the first time, it returns an error that the account is not found, but if the user tries to login again, then it proceeds with logging in. I tested if it stores a session cookie and it turns out that it doesn't (at least not for the first time). Next time the user tries to log in, it stores the cookie properly.

This is my first part of the login script, the one that checks if the captcha entered is correct and then it sets the session cookies and redirects the user to the login page script that checks if the user exists.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $mode = $_GET['mode'];
 if($mode == 'login')
 {
     require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "---";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        header('Location: http://cpalander.net/login.php?option=captcha');
    } else {
        $user = $_POST['username2'];
        $pass = $_POST['password3'];
        $_SESSION['pass3'] = $pass;
        $_SESSION['user3'] = $user;
        header('Location: http://cpalander.net/login.php?option=checkuser');
    }
    die();
 }
 else if($mode == 'sendticket')
 {
     require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "---";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        header('Location: http://cpalander.net/dashboard.php?option=sendticket&error=captcha');
    } else {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        header('Location: http://cpalander.net/dashboard.php?option=sendticket&subject=' . urlencode($subject) . '&message=' . urlencode($message));
    }
    die();
 }
 else
 {
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "---";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                 $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                 $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        header('Location: http://cpalander.net/register.php?option=captcha');
    } else {
        $_SESSION['user2'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['pass2'] = $_POST['password'];
        $_SESSION['mail2'] = $_POST['email'];
        header('Location: http://cpalander.net/makeacc.php');
    }
    die();
 }
 ?>
```

And this is the part of code that checks if the user exists and redirects the user in case of an error:

```
<?php session_start();

 $data = $_GET["option"];
 $user = $_SESSION['user3'];
 $pass = $_SESSION['pass3'];

 function generateRandomString($length = 10) 
                    {
                        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                        $randomString = '';
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
                        }
                        return $randomString;
                    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>....</head>...

<body>...    

...<?php
                if ($data == 'checkuser')
                {
                        $user = $_SESSION['user3'];
                        $link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '*******', '*******', '*******');
                        if ($link->connect_errno) {
        die('Failed to connect to MySQL: (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
     }                  
                        $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND active=1 AND banned=0");
                        $numrows = $result->num_rows;
                        if($numrows == 0)
                        {
                            $link->close();
                            session_destroy();
                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=login.php?option=notfound&user=' . $user . '">'; // This is the part that I used to check if the $user variable is set
                            exit;   
                        }
                        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                        $sid = $row['salt'];
                        $pass_h = hash('sha256', $sid . $pass);
                        $result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND password='$pass_h' AND active=1 AND banned=0");
                        $numrows = $result->num_rows;
                        if($numrows == 0)
                        {
                            $link->close();
                            session_destroy();
                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=login.php?option=notfound">';
                            exit;   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $link->close();
                            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                            echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=dashboard.php?option=home&user=' . $user . '">';
                            exit;
                        }
                        $link->close();
                }...</body>
```

Can anyone help me out on this one? Also, session_start(); is on top of the login page code.

Comment: You should hide your private key, and change :)

Comment: you have to have session_start() at the beginning of the 2nd part too if this is in another file

Comment: +1 for being one of the few that use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: @Jan Czarny - Yeah, was about to do that but pocesar beat me to it xD

Sebas - Yes, I have it at the beginning of the file, before any HTML output or anything

pocesar - I did some research and it seemed to be the best option to use from the start

Comment: Going to add my 2 cents as a comment as not 100% sure - but you might want to look into cross browser issues here, i once had an issue where cookies and sessions were not properly being set as i had to prompt the user for input - it seems to be becoming common place that a website must ask for interaction prior to setting a cookie now - worth looking into this?

Answer (score 0):

`session_start` should be present in all your files that need access to the `$_SESSION` variable. That means, if you are acessing unrelated files, you need to add `session_id() or session_start();` to them (the `session_id() or session_start();` part is to make sure that the dread the `Session already started` warning doesn't show up if a require/include to the same file were made in the same request)

`session_destroy()` destroys the session, you might just want to `session_unset()` instead, since `session_destroy()` will recreate the session when `session_start()` anew is called again. But if you really want to destroy the session and start again, a cross browser way is to call both `session_unset()` and `session_destroy()` (*cough* IE *cough*)

Also, you should take notice that apart from the question itself, you are allowing a XSS vulnerability on your code by passing the raw `$_POST` data to an URL without checking it.

Comment: I have session_start at the top of the code, I didn't want to post the full code cause it contains a lot of HTML and javascript that is unrelated to this issue

Comment: if the cookie isn't being set (`PHPSESSID` by default, then it's missing a session_start(), trust me). Even though you CAN start a session using AJAX (it's just a cookie afterall)

Comment: I edited my main post with the top of my login.php script, session_start() is there. I tried commenting out any session_destroy() or session_unset() lines but no luck

Edit: Can you point me to some resources on how to check it? What exactly should I be looking for when checking it? Special characters or something? Thank you.

Comment: the session won't be set (aka won't be included in the HTTP header) if there's other header modification before it. that means, if you you set your file to `error_reporting(-1)` you'll be seeing those errors that right now are "hidden" for you

Comment: another thing is to use a debugger, such as xdebug, so you can "walk" through your PHP code, so you know what is going on behind the curtains, that way you won't be blind trying to figure out what's wrong with non working code

Answer (score 0):

The code appears as if it should work. You destroy the session when the user is not found,
so there's no reason for it to work the second time and not the first... unless there is
something going on before, that relies on some session data, and which you did not post.

The only thing that seems iffy is the fact that the two login fields are named username2 and
password3, but I guess that you should get errors every time if that was a problem - unless
you generate "username2" or "username3" in response to different conditions?

Apart from that, I have some suggestions:

1) The

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
```

can be placed at the beginning, since you seem to use it anyway.

Then instead of

```
    $user = $_POST['username2'];
    $pass = $_POST['password3'];
    $_SESSION['pass3'] = $pass;
    $_SESSION['user3'] = $user;
```

you can just put (but more on that later)

```
    $_SESSION['pass3'] = $_POST['password3'];
    $_SESSION['user3'] = $_POST['username2'];
```

and you have no need of three separate die()s - actually I think you need none of them.

In this point:

```
if ($data == 'checkuser')
    {
        $user = $_SESSION['user3'];
```

you do not check that $_SESSION['user3'] is actually set. You might get errors
because of that. Actually, you had already assigned $user before (again without checking
that it had been set).

This row here is really dangerous

```
$result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user' AND active=1 AND banned=0");
```

since if I sent you a "username2" with a value of "bobby' OR ''='" your query would have become:

```
$link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='bobby' OR ''='' AND active=1 AND banned=0");
```

and since ''='' is always true, chances are that little Bobby Tables might have logged in, even if inactive and banned.

Then you store the password in the clear in the session, which I'll admit is little danger - but that is still worse than no danger at all. Why not store a hash instead?

```
$_SESSION['pass'] = hash('sha256', $_POST['password3']); // unsalted password
$_SESSION['user'] = hash('sha256', $_POST['username2']); // unsalted username

...

$link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA2(username,256)='$user'
        AND SHA2(CONCAT(salt,'$pass'),256)=password AND active=1 AND banned=0");
```

Now whatever one might place into $_POST, it will be grinded and digested to two safe hashes. The
session no longer contains either username or password. The password is still salted. If either
the user is nonexistent, banned, inactive, or password is wrong, the query will yield no results,
and its cost will always be the same, defeating most timed attacks.

If you keep the username/pass in the clear, then you need to `mysqli_escape()` it to avoid a SQL injection attack (or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with bound parameters).

Comment: Thank you, I will use your suggestions, especially about storing a hashed password instead of a clear one. Also, how can I somehow format the username/password fields so it excludes any characters that might do some MySQL damage? I updated my code with strip_tags() but I'm not sure what else should be done. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid the "fields" part isn't going to work: you can do that with Javascript (e.g. jQuery validators), but one might always use cURL to force entry. You need to always treat user input as potential poison, unfortunately. MySQLi prepared statements are a strong barrier, or you can use escape functions to defang harmful input. `strip_tags` helps with JS and XSS attacks, but not against SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dates on this post I see I am late to the party, but I found this because I was having a very similar issue. See my post at [PHP code to replicate nocache=1 functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340965/php-code-to-replicate-nocache-1-functionality) .

Here's an experiment that may narrow the problem: Browse away from your page, go to your browser's cookies and delete cookies for that domain, browse back to the login page, then check to see if there is a PHPSESSID cookie. My guess is there won't be. Then try the login (which you say fails). THEN check cookies again - the PHPSESSID will be there. Then the next login attempt works.

NOW try this: Again clear the cookies for that domain, then browse to that login page with a `?nocache=1` at the end of the URL. This time there probably WILL be a PHPSESSID cookie, and this time the login will work the first try.

In my case that `?nocache=1` thing works, but it is not even needed when I'm running the same code locally on my localhost.

It seems definitely like a session handling setting on the server.