# PHP code to replicate nocache=1 functionality

Tags: php

Forgive my previous effort to explain question. This is my first post here and I need a little practice narrowing down the real issue. I have stripped down some PHP code to demonstrate the problem:

```
<?php
session_start();
$message = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if(empty($_SESSION['token1'])) {
        $message = "After post SESSION(token1) is not present<br/><br/>";
    } else {
        $message = "After post SESSION(token1) is present<br/><br/>";
    }
}
$_SESSION['token1'] = "abcxyz";
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php 
        echo $message; 
        ?>
        <form action="" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="submit" name="cmdSubmit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Scenario 1: When I browse to the page containing this code a `Submit` button appears. When I click that button it displays "After post SESSION(token1) is not present" (followed by the `Submit` button again). When I click the button again, then it displays "After post SESSION(token1) is present".

Scenario 2: When I browse to the page containing this code by appending "?nocache=1", it displays "After post SESSION(token1) is present" after the FIRST click.

Scenario 3: When I browse to this page on my localhost on my local pc (even without the "?nocache=1"), it displays "After post SESSION(token1) is present" after the FIRST click.

One observation that will definitely help: In the scenario 1 after the page initially loads I checked the browser cookies for that domain and see that no PHPSESSID cookie exists. After I click `Submit` once, the cookie is there. For scenarios 2 and 3 the PHPSESSID cookie is there after the first page load (and before clicking `Submit`). In every case I cleared cookies for the domain prior to browsing to the page.

As you can see, the session is started, and the session var is set. So why is it not recognized after the first postback? And, more importantly, how can I code it such that it is recognized after the first page load in every environment?

My first thought was that since adding "?nocache=1" to the URL makes it work correctly in all environments, if I could somehow code PHP to replicate that behavior that would solve it. But I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I've worked with sessions, but admit that this current experience has me stumped. I don't see how my question doesn't make sense (strictly speaking, my question is the first paragraph - the rest is just context in case it helps).

When I browse to a page using the "?nocache=1", a session cookie (PHPSESSID) is immediately created and everything works as planned. When I browse without the "?nocache=1", it takes a few postbacks before the PHPSESSID cookie to be created, and for the session vars to be fully usable. I do know that the session is storage on the server, but the cookie is needed.

Comment: So the question was, can the behavior created by "?nocache=1" be coded so that this doesn't need to be part of the URL?

Comment: I finally get what you're asking, and I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`?nocache=1` has no behavior *per se*. Why you think `?nocache=1` has a behavior is that the browser caches `index.php` and `index.php?someparam=someval` separately. It has nothing to do with the exact phrase `?nocache=1` meaning anything. Its being treated just like any parameter would be. Its also not stopping the caching from happening. The second time you call `index.php?nocache=1` you will be accessing the cached version, but it will be the cache for `index.php?nocache=1` not just `index.php`

> I have tried all the suggestions using meta tags (pragma, cache-control, expires)

Using meta tags for cache control will be ignored by most browsers. What you need to do is use `header()` in PHP to set the cache-control headers:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',true);
```

Should be done at the top of the page before printing anything.